# How to send CTRL-P to a web browser in Python

Tags: python, selenium

The aim of this is to open a browser window and save the site as PDF.

I'm writing Python code that:

```
1) Opens a web page
2) Does a control-p to bring up the print dialog box
NOTE: I will have pre-configured the browser to save as PDF instead of defaulting as printing to a printer)
3) Does "return"
4) Enters the file name
5) Does "return" again
NOTE: In my full code, I'll be doing these steps hundreds of times
```

I'm having a problem early on with control-p. As a test, I'm able to send dummy text to Google's search, but I can't seem to be able to send a control-p (no error messages). I'm using Google as an easy example, but my final code will use various other sites.

Obviously I'm missing something but just can't figure out what.

I tried an alternate method of using javascript instead of ActionChains:

```
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

This worked in getting the print dialog but I wasn't able to feed anything else in that dialog box (like , file name and location for the pdf).

I tried PDFkit, to convert the web page into pdf. It worked on some sites, but it crashed often (depending on what the site returned), the page was sometimes poorly formatted and some sites (pinterest) just didn't render at all. For this reason, I changed method and decided to use selenium and Chrome in order for the pdf to render just like it shows in the browser.

I thought about using "element.send_keys("some text")" instead of ActionChains, but since I'm going across multiple different web sites, I don't necessarily know what element to look for.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)

URL = "http://www.google.com"
driver.get(URL)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(5) #Give the page time to load

actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.send_keys('p')
actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.perform()
time.sleep(5) #Sleep to see if the print dialog came up
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Did you try key_down for Control and for P eighter ? ... as I know, send_keys is used to handle forms ( didnt use it jet so its just a guess )

Comment: Thank you StyleZ for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use autoit to achieve your requirement.
First do `pip install -U pyautoit`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import autoit
import time
DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
autoit.send("^p")
time.sleep(10) # Pause to allow you to inspect the browser.
driver.quit()
```

Please let me know if it's working.

Comment: Any idea on where to find the documentation for autoit? All I find is information on how to install it and a brief example typing hello world in notepad. I just need to know how to do a return.

Comment: I have created one small blog might be useful for you. [link](http://jbanshpal.blogspot.com/2018/02/first-basic-setup-and-example.html?m=1) In additional install **autoit** you can refer help file available in `SciTE Script editor`

Comment: Again, thank you very much Jitendra. The documentation here showed me the character sequence: https://documentation.help/AutoItX/Send.htm

Comment: @Luc Could you accept this answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Done. Again, thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('P').key_up    
(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: Thank you anish, but unfortunately, same result. No print dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

check this out :

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P)
// CTRL+P is now pressed
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
```