# How to Print to PDF from .htm?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I have read through a few questions/answers that provide test codes to print to pdf using Selenium(chromedriver) that work for standard web pages - see below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from selenium import webdriver

appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}

profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState)}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='PATH_TO\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184647/how-to-send-ctrl-p-to-a-web-browser-in-python/54185741')
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

but does not work for a .htm path:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/857855/000085785520000011/ucbi1231201910-k.htm

i.e.

```
driver.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/857855/000085785520000011/ucbi1231201910-k.htm')
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

I can manually Save as PDF so not sure what to do

Comment: see [How to convert webpage into PDF by using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359083/how-to-convert-webpage-into-pdf-by-using-python). I can save this page in PDF using first answer - without Selenium. It creates PDF with 141 pages. And it can be problem for Selenium - too many data which needs too much time to generate PDF

Comment: You mind sending your code?  I tried to install PyQT5 and caused some issues with Conda/Spyder (wouldn't open) and had to uninstall/install again.

Comment: I used code from first answer - `import pdfkit` `pdfkit.from_url(' https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/857855/000085785520000011/ucbi1231201910-k.htm', 'out.pdf')`. I don't knows if it need PyQT5 but I have it installed for a long time. I don't use Conda and Spyder so I don't know if it makes problem.

Comment: Ok cool, post mentioned different solutions - most of which involved pyqt, i'll try the pdfkit. Thanks!